# How to dynamically inject service into directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

My directive is to build out a scaffolded table with a delete button.  I have a service set up named Post, so when I call the directive I'm including a servicename property on the element.  How do I dynamically inject my service based on my service name attribute I'm including?  Or is there a better way to do this?

```
var lassoDirectives = angular.module('lassoDirectives', []);

lassoDirectives.directive('autoTable', ['parse', function(parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            modelname: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'http://local.angular.com/webroot/app/templates/directives/auto-table.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log(parse);
            $scope.deleteItem = function(id) {
                console.log(id);
                // rocket = modelname.query();
                //console.log(rocket);
            }
            $scope.check = function() {
                parse.get("Posts", 123, function(response) {
                    console.log(response.toString());
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Why pass the service name and not the service itself?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that is the best way to go around it. You should probably have a single service that is charge of all the data related to this `lassoDirective`, so you could just inject it as normal.

But you may be able to use the `$injector` provider like...

```
.directive('autoTable', function($injector) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      servicename: '='
    },
    controller: function(scope) {
       var service = $injector.get(scope.servicename);

       scope.deleteItem = function(Id) {
         del = service.delete({Id: Id});
         items = service.query();
       };
    }
  }
});
```

If you want your service to perform differently depending on the directive clicked, it may be better to just pass your service additional parameters relating to the directive? Not sure what your situation is so ignore this common if N/A.

Comment: well, I'm just trying to set something up where I can make queries to multiple item types. Projects, posts, people etc etc.  The idea is to build a directive that can be used to go out grab/update/delete any type of item I might want. The logic is always the same except for a few parameters so I figured passing in values would be the best thing.   Is there an example service that could fetch any type of data and automatically display it?  Rather than doing it as a directive?

Comment: Did some more browsing and found this. I'll give it a go and see if it works:

https://gist.github.com/ThomasBurleson/2432692